# MS Access 2010: Pass through queries are deleted

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I use PT queries to get data from SQL Server 2008R2.
The query with ODBC connection string is stored in MS Access Client and gets the variable SQL-string from this function, which I found Long time ago in the web:

```
'If QueryName is not provided or is an empty string ( = "" ) no query object will be created but the SQL statement or stored procedure will be executed (useful for DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE statements).
'If you provide the parameter QueryName a query will be created with the provided name (this is useful for a SELECT statement as you expect to retrieve the resulting data set).
Function SQL_PassThrough(ByVal SQL As String, Optional QueryName As String)
    Dim qdf As QueryDef
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef
    With qdf
        .Name = QueryName
                .Connect = TempVars!ConnectionString
        .SQL = SQL
        .ReturnsRecords = (Len(QueryName) > 0)
        If .ReturnsRecords = False Then
           .Execute
        Else
            If Not IsNull(CurrentDb.QueryDefs(QueryName).Name) Then
                CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete QueryName
            End If
            CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Append qdf
        End If
        .Close
    End With
    Set qdf = Nothing
ExitHere:
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description

    Resume ExitHere
End Function
```

TempVars!ConnectionString contains the Connection string, which is stored in a table.

Everything works fine while the SQL-String (e.g. "EXEC dbo.spLookupSomething") Returns 0 records.

From time to time - and I cannot find out when or why - the PT query is DELETED at all from the Access objects and not appended anymore.
I noticed, that the function starts with

```
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef
```

although the query with exact this Name is already existing. But in most of the times it works (seems to overwrite the existing query) but sometimes it does not work at all.

I start all my PT queries from code like this:

```
strsql=""EXEC dbo.spLookupSomething"
call SQL_PassThrough(strsql, "PT_LookupSomething")
```

It is even very difficult to reproduce this behaviour. I tried to run the code more times (knowing that it Returns 0 !!), - nothing happens.

But sometime I can see in dev environment of the datebase, that the query disappears at the first run and the code crashed of course.

Any idea, WHY this happens and how to avoid it? It seems that the deletion and the appendage does not work properly all the time.

Thanks 
Michael

Comment: When the code fails has it executed this line `MsgBox Err.Description`?

Comment: no, because I deactived the msgbox. But without error handler it Points to "If Not IsNull(CurrentDb.QueryDefs(QueryName).Name) Then " with a Run Time Error 3265 - Item not found in this collection and I cannot find any incorrect code. But I will try with "On Error resume next", maybe it skips...

Comment: I've added the general VBA tag, to increase the views on this question.

Comment: Does the following reproduce the error:  Call you function `SQL_PassThrough "SELECT 1", "PT_NewNameNotUsedBefore"`.  I think the problem is with the method used to detect if an existing query already uses the provided name.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check for the existence of a query object like this:

```
IsNull(CurrentDb.QueryDefs(QueryName).Name)
```

It will raise an error at once. You will have to loop the QueryDefs collection to see if the name is present.

But why delete and create the query? Just leave it once created and adjust the SQL before you run it.

Comment: I am not ready with my modifications, but I think your thoughts are correct. Without error handler I get exact at this code "IsNull(CurrentDb.QueryDefs(QueryName).Name)" the error and I cannot even skip it with "On error resume next".

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interesting, here is my modified function, which hopefully avoids the deletion of the permanent stored queries in my database:

```
Function SQL_PT(ByVal SQL As String, Optional QueryName As String)  Dim qdf As QueryDef

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

If Len(QueryName) = 0 Then 'temp query    
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")
    With qdf
        .Connect = TempVars!ConnectionString
        .SQL = SQL
        .ReturnsRecords = False  
        .Execute
    End With

Else  
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(QueryName)
    qdf.SQL = SQL
End If

qdf.Close
Set qdf = Nothing

ExitHere:
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description

    Resume ExitHere
End Function
```

I do not delete and recreate the query anymore, but only modify the SQL of the query.

Michael